# Printing out a value in hex strange output?

Tags: c, hex, printf

```
int b = 0xf ^ 0xc;
printf("value is %04X", b);
```

Output is:

```
value is 0003
```

I know that the decimal value of the xor operation between `1111` and `1100` is `3` although I want integer `b` to be printed out in hex.

Comment: The value `3` is `3` no matter if it's printed in decimal, octal or hexadecimal representation. The only way that `3` would not be printed as `3` is if you print it using base 2 or base 3.

Comment: o shoot good call -__- its late i should sleep 

Thanks for that !

Comment: In case you were confused by the formatting of the output, `%#x` instead of `%x` gives the "0x" prefix that many people expect to see in front of hex numbers. Note that those two characters count against the field width, so you'd have to print `%#6x` to retain four hex digits in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**0003 is a hexadecimal value**; a hexa digit has values between 0..F

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, the hexadecimal digits are 0-9 and a-f. So a value less than (decimal) 10 will print just like in decimal, since the digit symbols are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's in hex format already. I guess you want 0x0003

```
int b = 0xf ^ 0xc;
printf("value is 0x%04X",b);
```